# Minimal Page - remove navigation list and the headers

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

I am looking to create a very minimal information page with no navigation list in the left and no headers above.

Can it be done?

[image: Screenshot below]

Comment: I'd like to create a wiki app without the left and top navigation, is that also possible? Reason: I will be putting data in a tabular form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an experimental potential approach on a modern team or communication site.  This modern page layout is still in "preview", and as such, may still have undocumented issues.  In addition, it's supported intent is to be used only for custom modern search pages, but that intent doesn't appear to be "enforced", at least not in its preview.

Setting this page layout on a modern page removes the header and navigation for a "full page" experience.

You will need to make sure Preview-mode features are enabled in your tenant, and you have updated to the latest version of [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps), then execute:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite" -useweblogin

Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity yourpage.aspx -LayoutType HeaderlessSearchResults
```

For more details

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/building-search-extensions

Comment: Thank you very much. I will just play around with SharePoint for the next couple of days and will let you know.

Comment: Hi William, to be honest I am just new to SharePoint and SharePoint Framework Extension might be too advanced for me so maybe I will just simplify my goal and that is to not go completely headless or "full page" but maybe just remove the left navigation part.. at least for now..

Comment: I just downloaded portable Node, NPM, Git per the tutorial I just watched but I just cannot download Yeoman. I am getting this error: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yo failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT

Comment: You don't need all that at this point.  I am not actually suggesting that you build anything in SPFx.  Although the intent of the `HeadlessSearchResults` page layout is to setup a page for SPFx search webparts, I am suggesting you use this layout for your own purposes. To run those two lines of PowerShell code, follow this guide to get started with PnP PowerShell: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Sadly, it seems like this has now been locked away only for pages set as the Search Results page for that web. @willman

Get's the following error message: 

Error details: This page has a layout that only works when it is used as a search results page. To set this page as the search results page, go to Search Settings for this site collection, and set this page as the Results Page URL. You can also change its layout back to another one that's supported to view it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do is to create a communication site. So you won't have a left navigation.
But header and O365 ribbon will still be visible.

Comment: I'd like to create a wiki app without the left and top navigation, is that also possible? Reason: I will be putting data in a tabular form just like in the image above.

Comment: I'd actually like left navigation, header, and 0365 ribbon removed

Comment: Thank you very much. I will just play around with SharePoint for the next couple of days and will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the page and insert a .css script to target and hide certain page elements.  Here's a [useful-looking post on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400139/how-to-hide-an-html-element-with-css) which has lots of answers.

Also, scroll down on [this page on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) to the section titled 'Hide an Element - display:none or visibility:hidden?'.  They suggest a couple of options for hiding page elements.  You can also tinker with the page, use their green "Try Yourself" buttons; for instance try changing the:

```
<h1 class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</h1>
```

See what happens when you remove the .css in the  element, so you'll change it to this:

```
<h1>This is a hidden heading</h1>
```

The heading will appear on the page.  You can use this method to hide even built-in Sharepoint page elements/sections.

Comment: Although using custom css is not a best practice on SharePoint Online: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-css-to-brand-pages

Comment: Okay. For this kind of tweaking, what's the best thing to use? A subsite main page, a page under a subsite, or a wiki site under a subsite? Basically, I want a tabular site without the left navigation pane, header and 0365 ribbon. Very basic and minimal look.

Comment: please note, I've not used Sharepoint Online, I'm still on 2013, so if you were to follow my Answer then you'll need to know the drawbacks (or risks?).  Regarding your question on where to create the page, personally I'd just test it out on a test site, I don't have an opinion on where the test site should be.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will just play around with SharePoint for the next couple of days and will let you know.